# rstrip not working as expected (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code:

```
file = open("file", "r")

array = file.readlines()

stats = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] # creating an array to fill

print array

sh1 = array[1] # breaking the array extracted from the text file up for editing

sh2 = array[2]

sh3 = array[3]

sh4 = array[4]

stats[0] = string.rstrip(sh1[1])

stats[1] = string.rstrip(sh2[1])

stats[2] = string.rstrip(sh3[1])


stats[3] = string.rstrip(sh4[1])

print stats
```

I was expecting it to strip the newlines from the array extracted from the text file and place the new data into a separate array. What is instead happening is I'm having a seemingly random amount of characters stripped from either end of my variables. Please could someone explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: Where the `string` comes from?

Comment: Why do you fill your array with 1s only to replace them later?

Comment: Do you start indexes from `1` purposefully? Remember that list indexes in Python are zero-based.

Comment: werkritter- yes. As well as my array, there was A string that I took from the file.
Tim- That's the only way I know to create an "empty" array.
Avinash- string was imported. It's a set of functions for python. I didn't show the code where I imported it, as I assumed that most people would know that that's what I'd done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the file using `with`, you don't need to call readlines first. You can simply iterate over the [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) in a list comprehension calling rstrip on each line:

```
with  open("file") as f: # with closes your file automatically
    stats = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

Why your code removes random characters is because you are passing random characters to remove, you are passing the second character from the *second, third,fourth* and *fifth* lines respectively to `rstrip` and stripping from lines *1,2,3* and *4* so depending on what the strings end with and what you passed different chars will be removed. You can pass no substring to remove any whitespace or specify certain characters:

```
In [3]: "foobar".rstrip("bar")
Out[3]: 'foo'
In [4]: "foobar  \n".rstrip()
Out[4]: 'foobar'
```

There is also no way you are removing data from the front of the string unless you are completely stripping the string. Lastly if you actually want to skip the first line and start at line `2` you would simply have to call `next(f)` on the file object before you iterate in the comprehension.

Comment: Before your reply, I had no idea what with was for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the full explanation of why my code wasn't working. That's really what I was looking for from this question.

Answer (score 3):

`sh1,sh2,sh3,sh4` are strings, so `sh1[1]` is the second character from the string.
rstrip will remove trailing whitespace, so you will put either 1 or 0 character strings into your result array.

I suspect you want something like:

```
stats = []
for line in open("file").readlines():
    line = line.rstrip()
    stats.append(line)

print stats
```

or all on one line:

```
print [ l.rstrip() for l in open("file").readlines() ]
```

Comment: I suspect string.rstrip refers to https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip

Comment: oh ok yea, didn't see the `string.` .

Comment: Also, if you want to strip the newline only, use `line.rstrip('\r\n')`.

Answer (score 2):

Use list-comprehension.

```
array = file.readlines()
print [i.rstrip() for i in array]
```